# Current going through resistor with Ohm's law?

Tags: physics

If the battery provides a 12 V electromotive force and the resistors are each 10 ohm , what is the current going through the resistor in region A in Amps?[image]

I assume I need Ohm's law: V = IR.

I would think for branch A, I would plug in the values 12 = I * 10

because there is only one resistor in branch A. This gives me I = 1.2, which is incorrect.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why do you assume that the potential difference between two ends of A is 12?

Comment: Lookup series and parallel resistance e.g. [here](https://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-Series-and-Parallel-Resistance).

Comment: The current has to flow through all three regions.  You can't ignore the effects regions B and C will have on the current.  Use parallel and series equivalent resistance methods to get a hold of the current and voltage values you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall resistance in the circuit = $10 + \frac{10}2 + \frac{10}3 = \frac{55}3$ ohm.

Current $I = \frac VR = \frac{12}{\frac{55}3} = \frac{36}{55}$ ampere

Answer (score 1):

12V is dropped across the whole resistor network, not resistor $R_a$ (the resistor in region A).  Less voltage is dropped across $R_a$.

Using Kirchoff's voltage law you can write:

$$V_a + V_b + V_c = 10$$

Using Kirchoff's current law you can write:

$$I_a = I_{batt}$$
$$I_a - I_{b1} - I_{b2} = 0$$
$$I_{b1}+I_{b2}-I_{c1}-I_{c2}-I_{c3}=0$$
$$I_{c1}+I_{c2}+I_{c3}=I_{batt}$$

And Ohm's law lets you write:

$$V_a=I_aR_a$$
$$V_{b}=I_{b1}R_{b1}$$
etc.

From that system of linear equations, and knowing that all the $R$'s are 10 ohms, you can solve for all the $V$'s and $I$'s.

Answer (score 0):

Note that total resistance is equivalent to $R + (R^{-1} + R^{-1})^{-1} + (R^{-1} + R^{-1} + R^{-1})^{-1}$

Which means that $I_{a} = \frac{V}{R + (R^{-1} + R^{-1})^{-1} + (R^{-1} + R^{-1} + R^{-1})^{-1}}$